# Is it safe to upload videos in cloud tools like video editors?

Tags: secret-sharing, exposure

What I have is a video file(with delicate pieces of frames in it) that I want to be edited using cloud apps, without looking further in site maps and that's not always possible too, if you have to share that file instantly, I'm not sure that general assurance of discreteness will be applied by the site owners and even will be deleted if I ask for that. that must make sure it may not fall in things where it's not intended to be used by someone, so I can share personal data. can owner rights be lost, or will high valuable information in upload files be lost, and security people are not often faced to upload their files to random sites to edit their work?

Many tools are available to give personal data away.

Comment: There might be some sites which are sufficiently trust worthy for you in your situation. But there is no way to make sure that some arbitrary site you choose will keep your data private. It might be part of their business model to reuse your data or it might be done accidentally due to a bug or data leak.

Comment: For minor edits an open source solution should be the choice. Give https://www.openshot.org a shot. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking a technical question, then no. If you upload your data to some website then website has the ability to do whatever it wants. Use offline editors to protect your privacy.

If you're asking a legal question, then it depends on the website's ToS and the laws that are applied to owners of the website. Also this is the wrong place for legal advice and I'm not a lawyer.